# Log rotation in Spring Boot service

Tags: java, linux, logrotate

I am deploying a Spring Boot 2.0.0-RC1 application as an [init.d service](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-initd-service), but I can't figure out how to configure the log rotation.
The app logs to /var/log/appname.log, but if I configure logrotate the logging stops after a rotation, because a new file is created, and the stdout/stderr redirection defined in the embedded script does not work anymore.

If I configure the log rotation in my logging system there are two problems: I can't create the files in /var/log, and I still have the redirection defined in the embedded script.

What is the proper solution for this?

Comment: Please always mark answers as accepted if they help to solve your problems. You can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) or any other. Having an accepted answer prevents the related post from appearing in [Unanswered Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) tab on the main page. Follow recommendations from [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

I'm facing the same problem in several applications and adding `copytruncate` param is the solution because your Spring Boot application doesn’t understand that the file has changed (truncated) and is acting like a `tail -f` command (see [How does the “tail” command's “-f” parameter work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18760/179547) for details).

**Example:**

```
/opt/payara41/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/* {
    daily
    copytruncate
    rotate 3
    dateext
    notifempty
}
```

---

> ### copytruncate
>
> Truncate the original log file to zero size in place after creating a copy, instead of moving the old log file and optionally creating a new one. It can be used when some program cannot be told to close its logfile and thus might continue writing (appending) to the previous log file forever. 
>   Note that there is a very small time slice between copying the file and truncating it, so some logging data might be lost. When this option is used, the *create* option will have no effect, as the old log
>   file stays in place

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, it's the option **copytruncate** in [logrotate](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-logrotate.conf/).